# Why can't my user log in with sql authentication?

Tags: sql-server

I follow this link step by step: [youtube](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dkr0dLwTgNX0&ei=FctaVf_KHa-HsQSYm4GoBw&usg=AFQjCNG8agMa0oksv5ToY4YTZXvwTV6kBw&bvm=bv.93564037,d.eXY) but when I want to connect my SQL server user, I get this error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to NOTHING-PC.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'ahbar'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476
```

What's happening here?

Comment: It looks like the login failed for that user. We're unlikely to trawl through the video; maybe offer some details for what you've done here, relevant code, etc?

Comment: This may help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Explained on the linked Site:

### Explanation

When a connection attempt is rejected because of an authentication failure that involves a bad password or user name, a message similar to the following is returned to the client: "Login failed for user ''. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)".

Your Username or Password is wrong!

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - Please do **not** post your sql password on stackoverflow.

Comment: You say username:aparat but your question says `Login failed for user 'ahbar'`

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode`?

In SSMS, login on with windows authentication, right click the instance and select property, then Security tab

[image: SQL Instance Property]